# Does S3 trigger need permission to call getObject?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a lambda function that is set up as a trigger on an S3 bucket and it gets called correctly but the lambda function fails when calling S3.getObject.

Do I need to separately set permissions for the lambda function in order to allow it to call getObject on the bucket that triggered the event?

UPDATE:

There seems to be a bug with AWS Amplify that means the S3Trigger bucket permissions get replaced by any API permissions you add.  They both create a policy using the same name and it seems whichever gets created last ends up replacing the previous one.

I worked around this by renaming the S3 trigger policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to provide a  Lambda execution role to access your Amazon S3 bucket.

You will  can use a policy similar to this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-execution-role-s3-bucket/

Comment: Thanks, see my edit in the question re a bug in amplify-cli or CloudFormation scripts.